# Firebase child node retrieving

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: my firebase]

I'm trying to retrieve all child nodes "userID" from firebase and store them in **userList** array list. Datasnapshot object **dsp** pulls all the data but it can't pass it to userList which always empty. Here is my code snippet:

```
groupList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child ( "Group Members" );

groupList.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        List<String> userList = new ArrayList<> ();

        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren ())
        {

            String  uID = dsp.child ("userID").getValue().toString ();
            userList.add ( uID );
        }
    }
```

What do you suggest to change in the code?

Comment: Try to intialize the userlist outside the onValueEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only looping over the direct child nodes of `Group Members`, so your `dsp` variable points to `Android11`, `mgrp` and `the lovers`. Since none of those has a property `userID`, the `uID` variable will indeed always be null or empty.

You'll need to loop over the nested level in your JSON (the keys like `MtNY...`) to be able to get the `userID` values.

So:

```
groupList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Group Members" );

groupList.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> userList = new ArrayList<> ();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren ()) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren ()) {
                String  uID = userSnapshot.child ("userID").getValue(String.class);
                userList.add ( uID );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, your comment saved my day :)